# Error message: Na/NaN/Inf when running linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, nan, na

I am trying to add a best fit line to a scatterplot where the y variable has been log transformed. My command is:

```
abline(lm(log(Epiphyte.Cover)~Seagrass.Cover))
```

And the error message that keeps appearing is:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
     NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
```

I have no values that are 0 in my dataset and all are positive numbers, anyone have any ideas how to get rid of this error? Let me know what other info you need! I am only new to R so please try and keep it simple as I have found the previously asked questions similar to this quite hard to follow. Thanks!

Comment: Where are your variables `Epiphyte.Cover` and `Seagrass.Cover`? Try putting them into data.frame and then supplying them to `lm`: `lm(log(Epiphyte.Cover)~Seagrass.Cover, data = dt)`. Also try see whether your data really have no NAs with `sum(is.na(log(Epiphyte.Cover)))`. If it returns 0, only then you can rule out that there is no problems with your variable.

Comment: @mpiktas I checked whether there are no NAs for sure by using the code you gave me and it returned 0 so that's good. Now when I try and put them into that lm code I'm getting the error message 'Error in as.data.fram.default(data, optional = TRUE) : cannot coerce class ""function"" to a data.frame'

Comment: @mpiktas I have figured it out - I just needed to add in where the data was coming from at the end of my abline, similar format to what you wrote in the lm line. It now looks like this:
abline(lm(log(Epiphyte.Cover)~Seagrass.Cover, data=MarineData2))
Thanks for your help!